# Compare two collections.defaultdict and remove similar values

Tags: python, collections, counter, defaultdict

I have two `collections.defaultdict` and trying to remove values from `d1` that are also in `d2`.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
d1 = Counter({'hi': 22, 'bye': 55, 'ok': 33})
d2 = Counter({'hi': 10, 'hello': 233, 'nvm': 96})
```

Ideal result:

```
d3 = set()
d3 = ({'bye':55, 'ok':33})
```

So far I have tried:

```
d3 = set()
d3 = d1 - d2
print(d3)
Counter({'bye': 55, 'ok': 33, 'hi': 12})
```

But this keeps the same value of `'hi'` even though I want to remove all similar ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, `d1` and `d2` are `Counter` objects they implement subtraction different than sets.

> From [**`collections.Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)(emphasis mine):
>
> > Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or **subtracting the counts of corresponding elements**.

> From [**`set.difference` or `set - other`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):
>
> > Return a new set with elements in the set that are not in the others.

That said, you can use `Counter.keys` and use `difference` just like sets.

```
keys = d1.keys() - d2.keys()
# keys = {'bye', 'ok'}

out = {k: d1[k] for k in keys}
# out = {'bye': 55, 'ok': 33}
```

Comment: Just as a follow up- how would I compare only the first 2 values of d1 with first 2 values of d2? (since can't do d1[:2] and err is 'unhashable type :slice'')

Comment: 'the first 2 values' ordered by value?

Comment: @dawg yes exactly

Comment: `d1.most_common(2)` gets the 2 greatest values. `d1.most_common(2).keys() - d2.most_common(2).keys()`

Comment: @dawg Has the perfect solution @sarah Here's the link to [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

Comment: @Ch3steR An AttributeError doesn't seem "perfect" to me :-P

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode haha :p forgot `.most_common` returns a list.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary comprehension

```
d3 = {k: v for k, v in d1.items() if k not in d2}
print(d3)
```

Result:

```
{'bye': 55, 'ok': 33}
```

Answer (score 3):

> trying to remove values from `d1` that are also in `d2`

```
for k in d2:
    d1.pop(k, None)
```